# How to fetch config file details for specific environment

Tags: c#, json, automation, environment-variables, app-config

I have a appSetting.json file which contains data segregatted by different test environments. I want to fetch data only of specific environment. I the below code I am getting null value in envConfig.

```
public static EnvironmentData GetConfigData()
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appSetting.json").Build();

    var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment"); //QA

    var appSetting = config.Get<AppSetting>();

    EnvironmentData envConfig = appSetting.appData
                    .Where(x => x.environment == env).Select(x => x.environmentData) as EnvironmentData;

    return envConfig;
}
```

AppSettings.cs

```
public class AppData
{
    public string environment { get; set; }
    public EnvironmentData environmentData { get; set; }
}

public class EnvironmentData
{
    public string baseUrl { get; set; }
    public string conn_string { get; set; }
}

public class AppSetting
{
    public List<AppData> appData { get; set; }
}
```

appSetting.json

```
{
   "appData":[
      {
         "environment":"QA",
         "environmentData":{
            "baseUrl":"QA_Base_URL",
            "conn_string":"QA dummy string"
         }
      },
      {
         "environment":"UAT",
         "environmentData":{
            "baseUrl":"UAT_Base_URL",
            "conn_string":"UAT dummy string"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

In the above code I am able to fetch all the json data into appsetting variable. I want to get data according to my environment which is set in environmnet variable.

Comment: `appSetting.appData.Single(x => x.environment == env).environmentData`

Comment: You can also specify a appsettings per environment with the appropriate settings, as opposed to having it all consolidated into one. During startup, you can derive the environment and load the appropriate settings.

Comment: yeah... different files is the way ... but if you reallly want then you may have config like this `{
 "QA":{
    "baseUrl":"QA_Base_URL",
    "conn_string":"QA dummy string"
 }
 ,
 "UAT":{
    "baseUrl":"UAT_Base_URL",
    "conn_string":"UAT dummy string"
 } /*other stuff*/
}` and then use `config.GetValue<EnvironmentData>(env)` (or even use injections of `IOption<EnvironmentData>` instead static methods)

Comment: @AnthonyForloney appsettings per environment would increase number of files, so I thought of going with this approach. Any advantage for having different appsettings or disadvantage in this approach?

Comment: An appsetting per environment has significant benefits over a single file. It improves organization of settings and simplifies the process when needing to add onto or locate specific values for a known environment. It also is supported out of the box and addresses the problem that you're facing currently. When considering tradeoffs between the two, I would lean more towards those benefits whereas increasing the number of files shouldn't be a concern, IMO.

Comment: Also security; your DEV server should know nothing about how your UAT server is configured. If someone hacks into your DEV server, they don't gain access to every configuration. You should have a single appsettings.json file that your code reads from. That file's contents change based on what environment it is running in (which could be written via a CI/CD process to simplify configuration, for example)